# Creating basic formula for workforce and manhours

Tags: equation, mathematical-expressions

I am in the process of creating a basic maths formula for my application.But I am not getting an idea, please find below situation.
I have 2 country name say c1 and c2.

1. Percentage of man hours (how to find based on a1 and a2)

a1.Man-hours of c1 countries employees in a job category in a contract type.

a2.Man-hours of c2 countries employees in a job category in a contract type.

Not able to find percentage of man hours based on a1 and a2

2.percentage of compensation value in workforce.(how to find based on a1,a2,a3 and a4)

a1.compensation per hour of c1 countries employees in a job category in a contract type.

a2.total man hours of c1 countries employees in a job category in a contract type.

a3.compensation per hour of c2  countries employees in a job category in a contract type.

a4. total man hours of c2 countries employees in a job category in a contract type.

I am not getting an idea how to write basic formula  for 1 and 2.please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about arithmetic, not about programming.

Comment: The tags are "equation" and "mathematical-expressions".  While I agree the problem seems basic -- I think these are valid topics for Stackflow, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your end goal is -- so I apologize if I'm over simplifying your problem.  You'll need to add more details about your desired outcome if this isn't helping you to get on track.

1. Let's assume:
   N - Job Category # (job category 1, job category 2... n)
   Mn - contract type # for Category n (type 1, 2....n)

Perhaps you want to find percentages against a total in both countries?  So we need to calculate first a total number of man hours...

[image]
and
[image]

Where, for instance, A1.1.2.hours is the number of man hours for C1, job category 1, contract type 2.  And...

Total Man Hours = Total C1 + Total C2.

Now, for any various percentages you are trying to calculate -- use your totals to get the information you want.

Examples:
What percentage of man hours for C1 are generated from job category 5 contract type 2?
%hours = A1.5.2.hours/Total for C1

What percentage of man hours for C1 and C2 are generated from job category 2 contract type 3?
%hours = (A1.2.3.hours + A2.2.3.hours)/(Total Hours C1+C2)

2. For percentages of compensation -- the solution is very similar, except you have to keep in mind to multiply compensation ($/hr) by man hours (hr) to achieve a result in $$$.  Everything you do above can be modified to talk $ instead of hours.  For instance...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have 5 categories and 2 contract types.i got confusion in percentage of compensation.i am also not getting A1 and A2 variables.i am not calculating based on individual but based on the entire category and contract type even though it's 5 and 2 respectively.